# Generate all combinations, of all lengths, in R, from a vector

Tags: r, combinations

Suppose I have the vector `["a","b","c"]`, then I'd like to create a list of vectors of all the **unique** combinations, of all sizes (order does not matter):

```
["a"]
["b"]
["c"]
["a","b"]
["a","c"]
["b","c"]
["a","b","c"]
```

How can I do this in R?

Comment: It has not been answered. The linked question does not return a list of lists.

Comment: Just remove the `do.call(c, ...)` wrapper, then it will be a list of lists.

Answer (score 17):

We can try with `combn`

```
do.call("c", lapply(seq_along(v1), function(i) combn(v1, i, FUN = list)))
```

#### data

```
v1 <- letters[1:3]
```

Comment: This does not return an array of arrays though.

Comment: @CodeGuy What you have showed is a structure in another language.  In R, vector structure is not as the one you showed.  Also, in `R`, array can be either matrix (2 dimensional) or higher dimensions (with lengths equal).  However, a `list` can accomodate vectors of different length.  THat is the reason I place the vectors in a `list`

Comment: we found the Java progammer ;-), do you need it the way you outlined in your Question, if so just do this lapply(seq_along(v1), function(i) combn(v1, i, FUN = list))

Comment: though I might add @akrun answer is better a data structure.