# How to calculate common values across different groups?

Tags: r, dplyr, igraph

I am trying to create a data frame for creating network charts using *igraph* package. I have sample data "mydata_data" and I want to create "expected_data".

I can easily calculate number of customers visited a particular store, but how do I calculate common set of customers who go to store x1 & store x2 etc.

I have 500+ stores, so I don't want to create columns manually. Sample data for reproducible purpose given below:

```
mydata_data<-data.frame(
  Customer_Name=c("A","A","C","D","D","B"),
  Store_Name=c("x1","x2","x2","x2","x3","x1"))

expected_data<-data.frame(
 Store_Name=c("x1","x2","x3","x1_x2","x2_x3","x1_x3"), 
 Customers_Visited=c(2,3,1,1,1,0))
```

Comment: should there also be a row with `x1_x2_x3` or you want combinations of only 2 `Store_Name` at a time ?

Comment: Only 2 store at a time ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible solution via `dplyr` is to create a list with all the combos for each customer, unnest that list, count and merge with a data frame with all the combinations, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
    group_by(Customer_Name) %>%
    summarise(combos = list(unique(c(unique(Store_Name), paste(unique(Store_Name), collapse = '_'))))) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    group_by(combos) %>%
    count() %>%
    right_join(data.frame(combos = c(unique(df$Store_Name), combn(unique(df$Store_Name), 2, paste, collapse = '_'))))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 6 x 2
> # Groups:   combos [?]
>   combos     n
>   <chr>  <int>
> 1 x1         2
> 2 x2         3
> 3 x3         1
> 4 x1_x2      1
> 5 x1_x3     NA
> 6 x2_x3      1
> ```

**NOTE:** Make sure that your `Store_Name` variable is a character *NOT* factor, otherwise the `combn()` will fail

Answer (score 2):

Here's an `igraph` approach:

```
A <- as.matrix(as_adj(graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(mydata_data), directed = FALSE)))
stores <- as.character(unique(mydata_data$Store_Name))
storeCombs <- t(combn(stores, 2))

data.frame(Store_Name = c(stores, apply(storeCombs, 1, paste, collapse = "_")),
           Customers_Visited = c(colSums(A)[stores], (A %*% A)[storeCombs]))
#   Store_Name Customers_Visited
# 1         x1                 2
# 2         x2                 3
# 3         x3                 1
# 4      x1_x2                 1
# 5      x1_x3                 0
# 6      x2_x3                 1
```

---

Explanation: `A` is the adjacency matrix of the corresponding undirected graph. `stores` is simply

```
stores
# [1] "x1" "x2" "x3"
```

while

```
storeCombs
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "x1" "x2"
# [2,] "x1" "x3"
# [3,] "x2" "x3"
```

The main trick then is how to obtain `Customers_Visited`: the first three numbers are just the corresponding numbers of neighbours of `stores`, while the common customers we get from the common graph neighbours (which we get from the square of `A`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible way to get the data

Here's a helper function adapted form here: [Generate all combinations, of all lengths, in R, from a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40049313/generate-all-combinations-of-all-lengths-in-r-from-a-vector)

```
comball <- function(x) do.call("c", lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) combn(as.character(x), i, FUN = list)))
```

Then you can use that with some tidy verse functions

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

mydata_data %>% 
  group_by(Customer_Name) %>% 
  summarize(visits = list(comball(Store_Name))) %>% 
  mutate(visits = map(visits, ~map_chr(., ~paste(., collapse="_")))) %>% 
  unnest(visits) %>% 
  count(visits)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, with `base` R:

Get the list of all possible stores

```
all_stores <- as.character(unique(mydata_data$Store_Name))
```

Find the different combinations of 1 or 2 stores :

```
all_comb_store <- lapply(1:2, function(n) combn(all_stores, n))
```

For each number of stores combined, get the number of customers that visited both and then combined this value in a `data.frame` with the names of the stores:

```
do.call(rbind, 
        lapply(all_comb_store, 
               function(nb_comb) {
                 data.frame(Store_Name=if (nrow(nb_comb)==1) as.character(nb_comb) else apply(nb_comb, 2, paste, collapse="_"), 
                            Customers_Visited=apply(nb_comb, 2, 
                                                    function(vec_stores) {
                                                       length(Reduce(intersect, 
                                                              lapply(vec_stores, 
                                                                     function(store) mydata_data$Customer_Name[mydata_data$Store_Name %in% store])))}))}))
#  Store_Name Customers_Visited
#1         x1                 2
#2         x2                 3
#3         x3                 1
#4      x1_x2                 1
#5      x1_x3                 0
#6      x2_x3                 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using *dplyr*: self join, then make group and get unique count. This should be a lot quicker compared to other answers where all combinations are considered.

**Note:** it doesn't show non-existent pairs. Also, here `x1_x1` means, of course, `x1`.

```
left_join(mydata_data, mydata_data, by = "Customer_Name")  %>%
  transmute(Customer_Name,
            grp = paste(pmin(Store_Name.x, Store_Name.y),
                        pmax(Store_Name.x, Store_Name.y), sep = "_")) %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  summarise(n = n_distinct(Customer_Name))

# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#   grp       n
#   <chr> <int>
# 1 x1_x1     2
# 2 x1_x2     1
# 3 x2_x2     3
# 4 x2_x3     1
# 5 x3_x3     1
```

**Data** without factors:

```
mydata_data<-data.frame(
  Customer_Name=c("A","A","C","D","D","B"),
  Store_Name=c("x1","x2","x2","x2","x3","x1"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```